# Products Attributes don´t change after Products Importation

Tags: database, magento, importerror, product, import-from-excel

**I hope someone could help me with this:**

I imported some products to Magento and everything seems to have gone ok. After importing these products I realized something was wrong:

- Tiles and description texts were corrupted, accents were not added and were replaced with other rare fonts.
- Meta information was not imported.
- Only 1 image for each product was imported.
- No reviews in the Review tab for some imported products

This is not a big deal, since you can edit this texts and change it. 
**THE PROBLEM IS I CHANGE THE TEXTS BUT I DON´T SEE ANY CHANGES!** I also tried to add a new product and in the backend and everything seems to be ok, but it does not appear in the frontend! :-( Changing prices and adding images works fine.

Here is an example of an imported product with errors in texts and title: http://www.studiomusiconline.cl/sennheiser-ew-122-p-g3-sistema-inalambrico-con-microfono-clip-me-4.html

Here is an example of an imported product that shows no reviews in the review tabs: http://www.studiomusiconline.cl/orange-crush-20rt-negro-1x8-amplificador-de-guitarra-combo.html

I did all the things that should be done for apply changes and then see them in the frontend without problems:

- Index Management was Reindexed (all)
- I deleted var/cache
- CDN cache was refreshed
- Cleared browser cache

**WHAT COULD BE THE PROBLEM? MAYBE DATABASE WAS CORRUPTED AFTER IMPORTATION?
PLEASE IF ANYONE KNOWS SOMETHING ABOUT THIS, HELP ME!**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you sure that you clear all kind of the cache?